# <script> tag changes to <s-cript> in tinymce

Tags: joomla, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE on my Joomla website.
I made script tags allowed in TinyMCE configuration.

now when I add script tag into the code, after saving, words like script and javascript change to s-cript and j-avascript. see the code below:

```
<div id="15354385923149200"><s-cript type="text/J-avaScript" src="https://www.aparat.com/embed/58aFO?data[rnddiv]=15354385923149200&amp;data[responsive]=yes"> </s-cript></div>
```

why does this happen? how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of searching around leads me to guess you are using RSFirewall and that product is causing this change.  I found a few posts online that reference RSFirewall making this change.

https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsfirewall-user-guide/frequently-asked-questions/rsfirewall-doesnt-allow-me-to-add-html-css-or-javascript-to-a-module.html

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks A LOT. what did you search?

Comment: I just used Google to search for `<s-cript` and found multiple references to that RSFirewall product.